# Variables calculating from one thread to another

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a Sub which I'm running multiple times in separate threads. I have running total variables in the Sub. The values of the variables seem to get added between threads. What am I doing wrong here?

Code to call the function from multiple threads:

```
Dim theradArray(dt.Rows.Count) As System.Threading.Thread 'Array of thread for each line
Dim threads As List(Of System.Threading.Thread) = New List(Of System.Threading.Thread)
Dim thr As System.Threading.Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf 
StockTransactionReport)
threads.Add(thr)
threads.LastOrDefault().Start(stockTransaction)
```

The Sub:

```
Private Sub StockTransactionReport(ByVal StockTransaction As Object)
    'Database query happens here
    Dim RunningTotals As RunningTotals
    NewRunningTotalsSales.dGTAvgCost += RunningTotals.dGTAvgCost
    'File is written to here
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use that same `(sourceObject).StockTransactionReport()` and/or it uses the same `NewRunningTotalsSales.dGTAvgCost` in every thread, then they ought to be added together.  IIRC, you have to make different objects per thread or else they're the same objects/variables.  If you make something new in a thread, then it will be thread-specific, but if it pre-existed, then it's thread-common so you need to associate separate objects with different threads.

Comment: Can't disagree with what @RBarryYoung has said.  Generally speaking you're heading for a world of hurt passing information across threads like this.  Better options would be to use something like a background worker where you can handle the Worker Completed event or implement an async\await pattern

Comment: @RBarryYoung, so if I have a thread calling a function which uses certain objects, how would I make them different? Could I user something like a random variable and call the object NewRunningTotalsSales(random).dGTAvgCost?

Comment: What Class/Object is `StockTransactionReport` in?  Basically you need another instance of that object every time you create your thread.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, it's just a Sub within the VB class. How do you instantiate a new instance of a Sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways of doing this, but this might work in your case without too much effort. Use `Static` to declare that the object instance is the same across all calls to the method. (btw you never created an instance, so your question mustn't show your actual code)

```vb
Private Sub StockTransactionReport(ByVal StockTransaction As Object)
    'Database query happens here
    Static RunningTotals As New RunningTotals()
    NewRunningTotalsSales.dGTAvgCost += RunningTotals.dGTAvgCost
    'File is written to here
End Sub
```

And in the RunningTotals class, which we don't see, you can use a thread-safe collection to account for adds coming from different threads

```vb
Public Class RunningTotals
    Private numbers As New Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of Double)
    Public Sub Add(value As Double)
        numbers.Add(value)
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property dGTAvgCost As Double
        Get
            Return numbers.Average()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

It occurred to me your `RunningTotals` may be a class with all shared members, in which case your original code was... right, and you don't need to create an instance, but you also wouldn't need to create a variable for that either so I'm not sure...